# Recognizing digits with OpenCV and Python (Simple digit OCR)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

So I'm trying to create a program that can see what number an image is and print the integer in the console. (I'm using python 3)

For example that the program recognizes that the following image (an actual image the program has to check) is number 2:

[image: number 2]

I've tried to just compare it with an other image with the 2 in it with `cv2.matchTemplate()` but each time the blue pixels rgb values are a little bit different for each image and the image could be a bit larger or smaller. for example the following image:

[image: number 2]

It also has to recognize it apart from al the other blue number images (0-9), for example the following one:

[image: number 5]

I've tried mulitple match template codes, and make a folder with number 0-9 images as templates, but each time almost every single number is recognized in the number that needs to be recognized. for example number 5 gets recognized in an image that is number 2. And if its doesnt recognize all of them, it recognizes the wrong one(s).

The ones I've tried:

- [Answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853628/how-do-i-find-an-image-contained-within-an-image)
- [Both codes from this tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)
- [And the one from this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/)

but like I said before it comes with those problems.

I've also tried to see how much percentage blue is in each image, but those numbers were to close to tell the numbers appart by seeing how much blue was in them.

Does anyone have a solution? Am I being stupid for using `cv2.matchTemplate()` and is there a much simpler option? (I don't mind using a library for it, because this is part of a bigger piece of code, but I prefer to code it, instead of libraries)

Comment: I think this is too broad/vague, and probably a poor fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Template Matching, a better approach is to use [Pytesseract OCR](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) to read the number with `image_to_string()`. But before performing OCR, you need to preprocess the image. For optimal OCR performance, the preprocessed image should have the *desired text/number/characters to OCR in black with the background in white*. A simple preprocessing step is to convert the image to grayscale, Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image, then invert the image. Here's a visualization of the preprocessing step:

Input image `->` Grayscale `->` Otsu's threshold `->` Inverted image ready for OCR

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Result from Pytesseract OCR

> 2

Here's the results with the other images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> 2

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

> 5

We use the `--psm 6` configuration option to assume a single uniform block of text. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619077/pytesseract-ocr-multiple-config-options) for more configuration options.

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold, then invert
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
invert = 255 - thresh

# Perfrom OCR with Pytesseract
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**Note:** If you insist on using Template Matching, you need to use scale variant template matching. Take a look at [how to isolate everything inside of a contour, scale it, and test the similarity to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401389/how-to-isolate-everything-inside-of-a-contour-scale-it-and-test-the-similarity/59402625) and [Python OpenCV line detection to detect X symbol in image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837175/python-opencv-line-detection-to-detect-x-symbol-in-image/58846516) for some examples. If you know for certain that your images are blue, then another approach would be to use color thresholding with `cv2.inRange()` to obtain a binary mask image then apply OCR on the image.

Comment: So I've tried your method, but there are still some numbers it wont pick up. for example it mistakes this 5 for a `-`: https://imgur.com/a/a1f5PSs and these are the threshed and inverted images: https://imgur.com/a/S4QwAg7. Is there a way to make it recognize that?

Comment: I'm getting `5` printed to the console with that input image. Are you loading the right image?

Comment: I'm sure I'm loading the right image. Are you using the exact code as in your anwser or could it be that something in the picture changed when I uploaded it to imgur.com (I'm using the exact code in your awnser except for the `cv2.imshow()` and `cv2.waitKey()`, but that shouldn't matter)? EDIT: I just downloaded the imgur image and it still gave me the `-`.

Comment: Yes I'm using the exact code, I simply downloaded the image (its a `.png` image) and get `5` every time. The `cv2.imshow()` and `cv2.waitKey()` are only for display purposes and shouldn't affect the console output. I'm using windows 10, `Python:  3.7.4`, `NumPy:   1.14.5`, `OpenCV:  4.1.0`, `pytesseract: 0.2.7`

Comment: Im also using windows 10, `Python 3.7.4`, but I'm using `numpy==1.18.1`, `opencv-python==4.1.2.30`, `pytesseract==0.3.1` wich are different from yours

Comment: That's very weird, the slight version differences shouldn't matter too much. If it works for other images I don't understand why it doesn't work for this slightly scaled image.

Comment: Hey, so I found the problem from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality. I created a 10px border arround each number image, and it works now 100% of the time (on the images I tested) thanks for your awnser, but could you please include a note that you may need to increase the border of the image for when other people come across this post?

Comment: @kaci, did you use `cv2.copyMakeBorder` to increase the border of the image?

Comment: No, I didn't. The number pictures are actually cropped images. The original is bigger and has black arround the number, so I just cropped the image like I normally would, but with a 10px border.

Comment: Oh you didn't mention that the original image had black around the number. That's probably why it was not working

Comment: No, those number images are the images that I used. But they come from other images that I cropped to those number images. I just made the program crop them to those with a black border, and checked those instead of those without a border

Comment: and it recognizes this `9` as a `o` with your program. You know any way to fix that? I already tried blurring the image, and chaning the `--psm` value a bit, but that only made it a `Q` or a `f` or a `}`. Image: https://imgur.com/a/ZT7tkYP

Comment: I'm getting `9` as output using the posted code, maybe the version differences do matter

Comment: What is your tesseract-OCR version?

Comment: I downgraded to tesseract-OCR version 3.05.02 and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure what exactly changed between the differing versions but glad to hear its working for you

Answer (score 2):

Given the lovely regular input, I expect that all you need is simple comparison to templates.  Since you neglected to supply your code and output, it's hard to tell what might have gone wrong.

Very simply ...

- Rescale your input to the size or your templates.
- Calculate any straightforward matching evaluation on the input with each of the 10 templates.  A simply matching count should suffice: how many pixels match between the two images.
- The template with the highest score is the identification.

You might also want to set a lower threshold for declaring a match, perhaps based on how well that template matches each of the other templates: any identification has to clearly exceed the match between two different templates.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to an OCR engine, just know you can build your own OCR system via a KNN classifier. In this example, the implementation should not be very difficult, as you are only classifying numbers. OpenCV provides a very straightforward implementation of KNN.

The classifier is trained using features calculated from samples from known instances of classes. In this case, you have 10 classes (if you are working with digits 0 - 9), so you can prepare a "template" with your digits, extract some features, train the classifier and use it to classify new instances.

All can be done in OpenCV without the need of extra libraries and the KNN (for this kind of application) has a more than acceptable accuracy rate.